# Sair da função quando chamar o cy.visit()

Tags: javascript, cypress

Olá, tudo bem ?
Estou com um probleminha no término da execução da função abaixo.
Estou tentando fazer com que a função **getMessageLink()** se repita por, no máximo, 3 vezes enquanto não obter o link. Porém, em todos os cenários, até mesmo quando o código alcança o cy.visit() com sucesso, a função se repete (não deveria).

Tentei reposicionar o trecho onde valida o contador e chama a função novamente, para fora do primeiro cy.request() mas não obtive sucesso.

```
if (retries < 3) {
    retries++;
    cy.log(`Tentativa ${retries}/3.`);
    getMessageLink();
}
```

```
Cypress.Commands.add("redirectToEmailUrl", (subject, domain, mailInbox) => {
    let retries = 0;

    getMessageLink();

    function getMessageLink() {
        cy.log("Aguardando a chegada do e-mail.");
        cy.wait(500);
        cy.request({
            method: "GET",
            url: `${mailinatorApi}/domains/${domain}/inboxes/${mailInbox}?token=${mailinatorToken}`
        }).as("getInboxMessages").then((inbox) => {
            const message = inbox.body.msgs[0];

            if (inbox.status !== 200) {
                cy.log("Erro ao obter ID da mensagem. Servidor indisponível.")
                return;
            }

            if (message == undefined) {
                cy.log("Caixa de entrada está vazia.");
                return;
            }

            if (message.seconds_ago < 15 || message.subject != subject) {
                cy.log("A mensagem ainda não chegou.")
                return;
            }

            cy.request({
                method: "GET",
                url: `${mailinatorApi}/domains/${domain}/inboxes/${mailInbox}/messages/${message.id}/links`
            }).as("getMessageContent").then((links) => {
                if (links.status !== 200) {
                    cy.log("Erro ao obter link da mensagem. Servidor indisponível.");
                    return;
                }

                if (links.body.links[0] == undefined) {
                    cy.log("O e-mail não contém nenhum link.")
                    return;
                }

                cy.visit(links.body.links[0]);
                return;
            });
            if (retries < 3) {
                retries++;
                cy.log(`Tentativa ${retries}/3.`);
                getMessageLink();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

**Edit: Fiz um "let visited = false" antes de chamar a função, e setei true após o cy.visit().**

```
Cypress.Commands.add("redirectToEmailUrl", (subject, domain, mailInbox) => {
    let retries = 0;
    let visited = false;

    getMessageLink();

    function getMessageLink() {
        cy.log("Aguardando a chegada do e-mail.");
        cy.wait(500);
```

**Mas a varável visited continua como false fora do escopo do if.**

```
                    [...]
                    cy.visit(links.body.links[0]);
                    visited = true;         
                });
            });
        console.log(visited);
        if (retries < 3 && !visited) {
            retries++;
            cy.log(`Tentativa ${retries}/3.`);
            getMessageLink();
        }
        return;
    };
});
```

Comment: precisa fazer sua função tratar um valor boolean caso tenha tido sucesso, assim pode avalizar junto com a condição dos replies, por exemplo `let clicked = false`.... depois `if (retries < 3 && !clicked)`.. e no seu código, quando consguir fazer o click, setar a variável `clicked = true`

Comment: @RicardoPontual obrigado pela resposta! Fiz uma alteração aqui na postagem. Implementei essa alteração com um valor boolean mas ainda sem sucesso, ele não recebe true fora do .then().

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema reescrevendo o código com base no modelo deste link: [Retry cy.request with retries limit and delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73234636/how-can-i-retry-cy-request-in-cypress-with-delay-and-retry-limit).

Se um dia for útil para alguém, este é o custom command completo e funcional que verifica as mensagens de uma caixa de entrada privada do mailinator:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("redirectToMailUrl", (subject, domain, inbox) => {
    const apiUrl = `${mailinatorApi}/domains/${domain}/inboxes/${inbox}`;
    const apiToken = `${mailinatorToken}`;
    let ms = 5000;
    let retries = 0;

    function req() {
        if (retries == 3) return;
        retries++;
        cy.log(`Aguardando a mensagem. Tentativa ${retries}/3.`);
        cy.wait(ms);

        cy.request(`${apiUrl}?token=${apiToken}`)
            .then((inbox) => {
                const message = inbox.body.msgs[0];
                let isStatusOk = inbox.status == 200 ? true : false;
                let isNotEmptyObj = inbox.body.msgs.length < 0 ? true : false;
                let isRecentMessage: boolean;
                let isRightSubject: boolean;

                if (isNotEmptyObj) {
                    isRecentMessage = message.seconds_ago < 20 ? true : false; // Alterar para "> 1" para testes
                    isRightSubject = message.subject == subject ? true : false;
                }

                if (isStatusOk && isNotEmptyObj && isRightSubject && isRecentMessage) {
                    cy.request(`${apiUrl}/messages/${message.id}/links?token=${apiToken}`)
                        .then((links) => {
                            const link = links.body.links[0];
                            isStatusOk = inbox.status == 200 ? true : false;
                            isNotEmptyObj = links.body.links.length > 0 ? true : false;

                            if (isStatusOk && isNotEmptyObj) {
                                cy.visit(link);
                            } else {
                                if (!isStatusOk) cy.log("Servidor indisponível.");
                                if (!isNotEmptyObj) cy.log("Nenhum link encontrado na mensagem.");

                                req();
                            }
                        });
                    return;
                } else {
                    if (!isStatusOk) cy.log("Servidor indisponível.");
                    if (!isNotEmptyObj || !isRecentMessage || !isRightSubject) cy.log("A mensagem ainda não chegou.");

                    req();
                }
            });
    }

    req();
});
```